# Overwriting Doctrine entities of a Third Party Symfony Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I always had this question in mind but I could always walk around the problem without facing it directly. Until today that is.

I'm having the following needs:

There's a third party bundle with a Entity that I want to overwrite so I can add some extra *Annotations* (Not just mapping annotations, JMS annotations, BeSimple Annotations, etc). The entity **is not** a *Mapped Superclass* nor I can seem to solve the problem by using *Interfaces*.

Can someone shred some light on the problem?

I'll explain with code:

Third party Bundle Entity Class I want to extend someway:

```
namespace Third\PartyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Third\PartyBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=20
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;
}
```

What I want to achieve:

```
namespace My\OwnBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use BeSimple\SoapBundle\ServiceDefinition\Annotation as Soap;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="User")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="My\OwnBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @Soap\ComplexType("int", nillable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=20
     * @Soap\ComplexType("string", nillable=false)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;
}
```

Notice that the second class has extra *Annotations* from Besimple.

Comment: In most bundles that ship entities there is a possibility to set your custom entity classes to use in the config. Did you check for such possibility?

Comment: Did you try to extend one user class from another user class, like this: class User extends BaseUser

Comment: @Wilt No, there's not that possibility.

Comment: @StephanYamilov I can but it does not serve the purspose I want.

Comment: You could make your own fork of the 3rd party library on GitHub and change the `User` class in the forked repository. IMHO it is a bad library if you cannot even customize the entities.

Comment: @Wilt Could you give me an example of a Bundle that allows to set a custom Entity? This third party is internal (it's another department the one that did it), I'm thinking about forking it and try to change the Entity behavior.

Comment: I added an answer with a reference...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bundle inheritance of symfony, like :

```
    class BorhUserBundle extends Bundle
    {
       public function getParent()
       {
          return 'FOSUserBundle';
       }
    }
```

Here is the documentation : 
[symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html)

So you just need to create entities in the same directory with the same name, and inherits the entities... This is how we extends the FosUserBundle

Answer (score 0):

In most bundles that ship entities there is a possibility to set your custom entity classes to use in the config. Did you check for such possibility?

An example on such a library/module [is the `ZfcUser` module from `ZF-Commons`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser). In that module there is a global key `'user_entity_class'` in the global config file that defaults to `ZfcUser\Entity\User` but can be used to point to an alternative entity class to use.

Check [the config file here](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/1.x/config/zfcuser.global.php.dist#L24) for reference.